# Passing state from child to parent component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent and child component, i want to pass the state(share) from the child component to the parent one in the props(isChecked), how can this be done?

```
export class Form extends React.Component<FormProps, {
    ...,
    isChecked?: boolean}> {
constructor(props: FormProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      ...,
      isChecked:false
    };
 private checkField = () => {
           const checked = this.state.isChecked
           console.log('check '+checked)
    }
 render() {

}
return <div><Input name="Name" required={true} isChecked={this.state.isChecked}></div>
}

export function Input(props: React.PropsWithChildren<{name: string, required?: boolean, isChecked?:boolean}>) {
 
  const [share, setShare] = useState(false);
 
  return <Fragment>
    <div>
      {props.name}
      <span onClick={(event) => {setShare(!share);props.isChecked = share;}}>Selection {props.required ? '(Required)': ''}</span>
    </div>
<div className="btn btn--dark btn--margin-left" onClick= 
     {this.checkField}> Verify</div>
  </Fragment>;
}
```

Comment: You seem to already be passing the state to the child using a prop.

Comment: @evolutionbox I need it from the child to be passed to the parent, when the user click on span

Comment: Pass a function to the child from the parent as a prop. The child can then call it which will update the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Child to Parent Interaction, you should pass a function as prop to the child from parent..

```
export class Form extends React.Component<FormProps, {
        ...,
        isChecked?: boolean}> {
    constructor(props: FormProps) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
          ...,
          isChecked:false
        };
     render() {
    
       return <div>
               <Input 
                 name="Name" 
                 required={true} 
                 isChecked={this.state.isChecked}
                 handleChecked={
                 (isChecked: boolean) => this.setState({isChecked})
                 }
                />
             </div>
    }
    

    export function Input(props: React.PropsWithChildren<{name: string, required?: boolean, isChecked?:boolean, handleChecked?: (isChecked: boolean) => void}>) {
     
      const [share, setShare] = useState(false);
     
      return <Fragment>
        <div>
          {props.name}
          <span onClick={
              (event) => {
                  setShare(!share);
                  if(handleChecked) {props.handleChecked(share);}
          }}>Selection {props.required ? '(Required)': ''}</span>
        </div>
      </Fragment>;
    }
```

Comment: props.handleChecked(share) -> Error:Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.

Comment: I have edited the code.. pls check..changed
`    export function Input(props: React.PropsWithChildren<{name: string, required?: boolean, isChecked?:boolean, handleChecked: (isChecked: boolean) => void}>) {
`

Comment: can you attach the error image or text here.. and im not sure where the error originates

Comment: it is working fine, but the problem is this props(handleCheck) i need to use it in one component not all the components. So when i did that ` handleChecked?: (isChecked: boolean) => void` it throws the error

Comment: Check now.. I have edited the code

Comment: Super,it worked :) but the state is sent to parent before it's value is changed in 'setShare':(

Comment: since setting state is a async batch process, it might be the issue.. but not sure because I'm not sure about your whole component logic

Comment: i edited my code, the main idea is that i want to verify onclick of 'Verify' that the user clicked on the span, so i passed the state to check it and show a message to the user

Comment: so do you want to pass on the `share` state or `!share` on span click event? as of now we are passing the inverse of share state ..

  as of now > `if(handleChecked) {props.handleChecked(share);}` but you are setting the local state as '!share'

is that the intended logic?

Comment: what i meant is: the span is by default unchecked, when the user click on it, its state change. So whatever it's state is i want to pass it to the verify function to show error message if it isn't checked

Comment: so is it kind of helper text .?. validating the input field

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use `share` in your parent component and if that's the case you must set the state in the parent and pass it to your child as a prop just as you did with `isChecked`.

Comment: i want to make isChecked = share

Comment: In that case what you want is to pass a function to your child that updates the isChecked state after user triggers click event. child components aren't meant to pass anything to its parents

Answer (score 0):

Very easy to do you just need to pass a `handleChange` prop to your child component from the parent component and then utilize it in the child component.

Checkout this [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-wozniak-7jd8x8?file=/src/App.js)